# Remove leading and trailing white spaces in TinyMCE text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to remove leading and trailing white spaces in TinyMCE text area.

```
var frontandbackremovedhere = tinyMCE.get('ID').getContent().trim();
```

I tried above but not working.how can I do this

for example

If I inset following text in editor

```
    Hi,          


Regards


kez
```

It will get the html as following

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Hi,<br><br>Regards<br><br></p><p>kez &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
```

I'm trying to remove it like this

```
<p>Hi,&nbsp; &nbsp;<br><br>Regards<br><br></p><p>kez</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var frontandbackremovedhere=$.trim(tinyMCE.get('ID').getContent());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let editorContent = tinyMCE.get('ID').getContent({format:'raw'}).trim();
tinyMCE.get('ID').setContent(editorContent);
```

Comment: wht is this "Let" ?

Comment: 'Let' keyword is introduced in ES6 which have its own benefits.
Have a look [http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ecmascript-6/](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ecmascript-6/)

Comment: The capital letter makes it look really weird.  The SO highlighter even makes it look like a classname when you have the caps.  But yes, "let" is a valid es6 operator.